# Signal to the user that two areas result in different navigation

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation, click

I'm building an application in which the user can select categories by clicking on the first heading (Leather), the image, or the second heading (12 Novelties). The categories are displayed as material cards, as seen in the following example:

[image]

The difficulty is, that a click on "Leather" (click area 1) should navigate to a different route, than a click on the image or "12 Novelties" (both click area 2), so we have two click areas:

[image]

My question is: How do I visibly distinguish the two click areas while trying to  stay as close to the current design as possible? I want to make it clear to the user, that, without hovering the mouse on one of the two click areas, they lead to different routes.

For clarity: "Leather" (click area 1) refers to a category, and "12 Novelties" (click area 2) refers to the latest twelve products in the category "Leather".

Thank you.

Comment: I would set an image linked to the 'Leather' category instead of 'Novelties'. That way, it is clear that the user will go to the category (which, I presume, will be the main goal). The 'Novelties' bar will then be a child (anchor) of the category.

Comment: @Levano thank for your answer. But how do i visibly distinguish the two click areas, even if I do as you suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Chevrons

Users are familiar with chevrons at the end of list items. They know that on click it takes them to a deeper page.
You could also add a width difference to the '12 Novelties' card to show that it comes under 'Leather'

[image]